# I am unable to set Onclick event on Imageview in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

Where ever i click on ImageView the onclick method is not hapenning. i mean it is not redirecting to my main.xml

//package name : **bunk**

//My cesem.XML :

//just a Textview and a Image View
- Indented four spaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Your Semester"
        android:textSize="25dp" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvSemCe"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
   />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/back"
     />

</LinearLayout>




//Class file: Cesem.java


package com.bunk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Cesem extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    ImageView back;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cesem); // cesem.xml

        back=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);// back is ImageView
        back.setOnClickListener(this);



    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v == back) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the element as clickable:

```
back.setClickable(true);
```

Or maybe you can't see a feedback beacuse of the content of click callback (setContentView..)

Try to log something inside the click callback, such as

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v == back) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
 }
```

Comment: not working :( can you please download it and check it ? docs.google.com/file/d/0B8kSGDgP5vndelVZRnJ0YUZ0U0k/

Comment: oops i mean this link
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8kSGDgP5vndelVZRnJ0YUZ0U0k/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.back)
```

instead of

```
if (v == back)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as:

```
public class Cesem extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    ImageView back;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cesem); // cesem.xml

        back=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);// back is ImageView
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v.getId() == R.id.back) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Activity.this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
            }
            else
            {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
   }
}
```

and register your Activity in manifest as:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Cesem" />
```

Comment: not working :( can you please download it and check it ?

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8kSGDgP5vndelVZRnJ0YUZ0U0k/edit

Comment: see my edit answer now it's working u need to just register your All activities in manifast

Comment: i'm able to see toast when ImageButton Clicked

Comment: just done as u hv done.. even register in manifest.xml ... still not working.. is that any website to learn? videos? please

Comment: try this code https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/Splash.rar?attredirects=0&d=1